Oracle regexp_replace entire matching word
Input:
ABC DEF GHIJ123A KLM GHIJ456B RST UVW GHIJ789C

Ouput:
ABC DEF GHIJ000X KLM GHIJ000X RST UVW GHIJ000X

So, I want to find all instances of words in the string that start with GHIJ and replace the entire word with GHIJ000X.
How can I achieve this in Oracle SQL?

You can do it like that:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
           'ABC DEF GHIJ123A KLM GHIJ456B RST UVW GHIJ789C',
           'GHIJ\w*',
           'GHIJ000X'
       ) AS replaced_string
FROM dual;


You can match either the start of the string ^ or a non-word character \W before the pattern you want to match to ensure that the pattern is at the start of the word:
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '(^|\W)GHIJ\w*',
         '\1GHIJ000X'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT 'ABC DEF GHIJ123A KLM GHIJ456B RST UVW GHIJ789C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FGHIJ EGHIJ123 GHIJ GHIJ123 ZGHIJK' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



VALUE
REPLACED_VALUE




ABC DEF GHIJ123A KLM GHIJ456B RST UVW GHIJ789C
ABC DEF GHIJ000X KLM GHIJ000X RST UVW GHIJ000X


FGHIJ EGHIJ123 GHIJ GHIJ123 ZGHIJK
FGHIJ EGHIJ123 GHIJ000X GHIJ000X ZGHIJK



fiddle
